# apoc refactor rename gives Procedure does not support implicit naming error

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I try to write a cypher query that extracts a set of labels, that share one specific label. After is selected the labels i try to rename them. Which means add a prefix to each of the labels andrename the labels in the graph with help of `apoc.refactor.rename.label`. Therefore i wrote the following query.

```
match (c:TheLabel) 
with collect(distinct filter( l in labels(c) where not l in ["UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL","TheLabel"])[0]) as curr_label 
unwind curr_label as cl 
with cl as cl, "AR_"+cl as nl
call apoc.refactor.rename.label(cl, nl) 
return null
```

But this query fails with the following error message:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 5, column 1 (offset: 214))
"call apoc.refactor.rename.label(cl, nl) return null"
```

I can't understand where i could use yield to get this query run.
I tried the first part separately i.e. return nl & cl after the with. This works fine. I also tried to use the rename function with one specific cl and cl that i got while trying the first part of the query. That is also working fine. Only the combination seems not to work.

Edit:

I figured out that every unwind seems to break the query never the less if I use the variable that is defined by unwind or not.
Minimal example that produces the same error:

```
unwind [1,2,3,4] as cl 
call apoc.refactor.rename.label("Test", "Test") 
return cl
```

Thanks in advance for any help or solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a procedure is defined to return any results, then the Cypher language requires that the [CALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/#query-call) clause must be paired with a `YIELD` clause -- even if you don't care about any of the results. The only exception is when the entire Cypher statement consists of just a `CALL` clause (this is referred to in the docs as a "standalone procedure call").

To quote from [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/#query-call):

> If the called procedure declares at least one result field, YIELD may
>   generally not be omitted. However YIELD may always be omitted in a
>   standalone procedure call. In this case, all result fields are yielded
>   as newly-bound variables from the procedure call to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Ok after trying around i figured it out. You need to yield at least one field of the return of the call for example:

```
unwind [1,2,3,4] as cl 
call apoc.refactor.rename.label("Test", "Test") 
yield total
return null // everything is possible for return.
```

I don't know why it's working but it works. Maybe it has to do something with the stream that the procedure produces, but I'm really not sure. If somebody knows why it solves my problem please comment.